# Image caching with Javascript - ajax reloads them

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, browser-cache

I've got some AJAX set at an interval to check the server for notifications, etc. Problem is the browser is not caching the images like I thought it would.

Every 2.5 seconds the interval is run and sets the innerHTML of a div from XML, including an image.

The text is fine, but every 2.5 seconds, the image is evidently reloaded, causing the text to shift.

Here is the JS

```
window.onload = function(){
    inth = setInterval(function(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){;
                    try{z=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("activity");}catch (er){z = "";}
                    for (i=0;i<z.length;i++){
                        zz=z[i].getElementsByTagName("time");
                        {try{timez =  zz[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}catch (er){timez = "";}}
                        zz=z[i].getElementsByTagName("str");
                        {try{ustr =  zz[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}catch (er){ustr = "";}}
                        zz=z[i].getElementsByTagName("user");
                        {try{user =  zz[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}catch (er){user = "";}}
                        zz=z[i].getElementsByTagName("act");
                        {try{act =  zz[0].firstChild.nodeValue;}catch (er){act = "";}}

                        ntxt = ntxt + "<div style='border-bottom: 3px dotted #DBDBDB; padding:.5em;'><div><span style='display:inline-block; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; line-height:14px; margin:0; padding:0;'><img src='avatar.php?size=14&hash="+ustr+"' style='height:14px; display:inline-block;padding:0;margin:0;' />&nbsp;"+user+"</span></div><span style='font-weight:bold;'>"+act+"</span><small> - "+timez+"</small></div>";
                    }
                    ntxt = ntxt + "</div>";

                    }
                document.getElementById('actstream').innerHTML=ntxt;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_not.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }, 2500);
    return false;
}
```

What is the simplest way I can prevent the images from reloading?

Comment: Which images are you talking about?

Comment: How do you know they're not getting cached? are you using your browser's network tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the **`"&hash="+ustr`** parameter that is included with the GET request might be acting as a cache-buster. If that parameter is changing each time, then each iteration will be considered a brand new request.

If that doesn't fix it, you might want to take a look at the `Expires` and the `Cache-Control` configuration on the headers.

Comment: session_start(); 
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 2 day")));

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to prevent them from reloading is not to rewrite the HTML and create a new `img` tag every 2.5 seconds.

It looks like your images are being set as `avatar.php?size=14&hash="+ustr+"`, where `ustr` is the important bit which identifies the image.

First, I'm guessing that the `ustr` value is meant to be the same each time? Check that the `ustr` value isn't changing each request. If it is, then as far as your code can tell, there really is a different image each time. You may want to fix your server code.

Rather than simply blasting a big pile of text into the `actstream` div's `innerHTML` property, I'd suggest putting ID's on each component - then you can find and update the time, str, user and act values individually.

Once you've done this, you can then save the previous `ustr` value (a javascript global variable is an easy place to put this, or you could re-read the `src` attribute from the image tag itself), and only update the image tag if the value actually changes.

If you *must* keep this nasty innerHTML blasting code, then I'd suggest checking the headers that your webserver sends when the browser downloads `avatar.php`. My guess is that you are not setting any [Cache headers](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?hl=de-DE), and so the browser won't cache previous images.